# Callback and anonymous functions in php with undefined parameters

Tags: php, callback, anonymous-function, lambda

How can I use a callback functions with undefined number of parameters?

I think an example could be better:

I have in my class two functions which are really really similar but a couple of lines. What I want to do is to call a function with the common code and passing a callback with the particular code. I use to do this using a template method pattern when working with differents objects, but this is not the case right now.

Some dummy code:

```
public function firstMethod($commonParam, $particularParam)
{
    //some common staff
    if ($whatever) {
        //more common staff
        //do something particular with $particularParam
    }

    return $something
}

public function secondMethod($commonParam, $particularParam1, $particularParam2)
{
    //some common staff
    if ($whatever) {
        //more common staff
        //do something particular with $particularParam1 and particularParam2
    }

    return $something
}
```

And now I want something like this:

```
public function firstMethod($commonParam, $particularParam)
{
    $lamba = function ($particularParam){
                    //do something particular with $particularParam
                };

    return $this->commonMethod($commonParam, $lambda);
}

public function secondMethod($commonParam, $particularParam1, $particularParam2)
{
    $lamba = function ($particularParam1, $particularParam2){
                    //do something particular with $particularParam1 and $particularParam2
                };

    return $this->commonMethod($commonParam, $lambda);
}

private function commonMethod($commonParam, $callback)
{
    //some common staff
    if ($whatever) {
        //more common staff
        //CALLING $callback. But how can a pass the parameters when it is not the same number for the anonymous functions?
    }

    return $something
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which PHP version you develop your application. In PHP 5.6.x there 's a splash operator involved. So you can simply use it as follows:

```
function bla($foo, ...$params) {
    // $params will be an array with all your parameters
}
```

In older versions of PHP you will get the same result with func_get_args()

```
function bla() {
    $numOfArgs = func_num_args();
    $parameters = func_get_args();

    return $something;
}

// call
$result = bla($param1, $param2, $param3, $param4);
```